# Add 1 or more email with append structure

Tags: abap

We have a table that is filled by a program with a web service. This table has customer data like custno, name tele1, tele2, addr etc. They want to add emails but they do not know how many fields each customer has. They told me that we can handle this by adding an Append Structure to the table. I look in the internet but I can't find a way to do this with Append Structure.

What they want is to have 1 record for Elias with all his data and under this to put his 3 email.

Can we do it with Append Structure and how.

Thanks in advance

PS. This is an important correction. **This is not a DB table but it is a structure**. This Structure ws_customer is used as IMPORT in order to pass the customer data for creating or updating the sap customer. So they asked from me to add an **APPEND STRUCTURE** and add dynamically as much emails as the customer has. For example the customer ELIAS with CUSTNO 145 ADDRESS BROWN 6 has emails asimof@gmail.com, asimof@hol.gr and asimof@greece.gr. The Append Structure will have 1 field and for the record of this customer we will have 3 emails.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Append structures are for standard SAP tables to add extra fields according to your needs. If it is a customer table, you can just modify the table and add more fields in SE11 as you wish. However if you add 3 fields for three possible email addresses and there is a customer with four email addresses , than you are in trouble. What about creating a new table just for the email addresses, you can create as many lines for each customers, as  you wish. Have a look at standard tables ADRC (addresses) and ADR6 (emails), this works exactly this way.

Comment: are you talking about a ddic table or a table that is defined by "TYPES..." ?

Comment: Please see my important correction.

Comment: What I wrote in my first comment, is still valid: if you add one field to the structure (with APPEND structure - if this is a standard SAP structure/table, if not, you can modify it without APPEND), you have field for 1 email adress, if you add two fields, than you have fields for 2 email addresses, and so on. If you add n fields and the customer has n+1 emails, than you are in trouble. Can you check, if you can keep the existing structure and add a table to the web service for the emails at the same time? So, you have one customer and as many emails, as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you add a table of email adresses to this structure? in my oppinion, you could do it just the way JozsefSzikszai described it.

When you have your structure, you can append a table to this structure and then you can always add as much email adresses to this table as you want

a example could look like this:

```
TYPES BEGIN OF your_structure,
  field1 TYPE string,
  field2 TYPE string,
  email TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF string,
END OF your_structure.
```

when you then have your variable of the type your_structure, you can add email adresses like this:

```
DATA your_variable TYPE your_structure.
INSERT 'email@adress.com' INTO TABLE your_variable-email.
```

When your_structure is a DDIC structure and not defined by code, you could append the table to the DDIC structure and use it just the same way

Comment: If my answer helped you, then an upvote would bei highly appreciated

Comment: Would suggest to use the predefined type string_table, otherwise a neat solution.